# $interval stops executing if an error occurs

Tags: angularjs, intervals

I have a function wrapped in an `$interval` (running on an infinite loop) that gets called every 5 minutes. The function calls a `$http` request on a promise within a try/catch block.

```
getProductDataPromise = $interval( function() {


    getProductData();


}, 5 * 60000 );
```

However, if `getProductData()` returns an error (say 400 Bad Request) then I am finding that the `$interval` no longer executes.

Is there a way I can recover from this?

Comment: Seems not: https://jsbin.com/duyimix/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Okay, well if there is no recovery, can you suggest an alternative method maybe?